# JavaBean wrapping with JavaFX Properties

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, model, javabeans

I want to use JavaFX properties for UI binding, but I don't want them in my model classes (see [Using javafx.beans properties in model classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187989/using-javafx-beans-properties-in-model-classes)). My model classes have getters and setters, and I want to create properties based on those. For example, assuming an instance `bean` with methods `String getName()` and `setName(String name)`, I would write

```
 SimpleStringProperty property = new SimpleStringProperty(bean, "name")
```

expecting that `property.set("Foobar")` would trigger a call to `bean.setName`. But this doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

Comment: Don't completely discard the idea of using javafx properties in your model classes. I added an alternative answer to the question you linked: it may be an approach worth thinking about.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `Simple*Property` classes are full, standalone implementations of their corresponding `Property` abstract classes, and do not rely on any other object. So, for example, `SimpleStringProperty` contains a (private) `String` field itself which holds the current value of the property.

The parameters to the constructor you showed:

```
new SimpleStringProperty(bean, "name")
```

are:

- `bean`: the bean to which the property belongs, if any
- `name`: the name of the property

The `bean` can be useful in a `ChangeListener`'s `changed(...)` method as you can retrieve the "owning bean" of the property that changed from the property itself. The `name` can be used similarly (if you have the same listener registered with multiple properties, you can figure out which property changed: though I never use this pattern).

So a typical use of a `SimpleStringProperty` as an observable property of an object looks like:

```
public class Person {
    private final StringProperty firstName 
        = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName");

    public final String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public final void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName ;
    }

    // ... other properties, etc
}
```

The functionality you are looking for: to wrap an existing Java Bean style property in a JavaFX observable property is implemented by classes in the `javafx.beans.property.adapter` package. So, for example, you could do

```
StringProperty nameProperty = new JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder()
        .bean(bean)
        .name("name")
        .build();
```

Calling

```
nameProperty.set("James");
```

with this setup will effectively cause a call to

```
bean.setName("James");
```

If the bean supports `PropertyChangeListener`s, the `JavaBeanStringProperty` will register a `PropertyChangeListener` with the bean. Any changes to the `name` property of the Java Bean will be translated by the `JavaBeanStringProperty` into JavaFX property changes. Consequently, if the underlying JavaBean supports `PropertyChangeListener`s, then changes to the bean via

```
bean.setName(...);
```

will result in any `ChangeListener`s (or `InvalidationListener`s) registered with the `JavaBeanStringProperty` being notified of the change.

So, for example, if the Bean class is

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

public class Bean {

    private String name ;
    private final PropertyChangeSupport propertySupport ;

    public Bean(String name) {
        this.name = name ;
        this.propertySupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public Bean() {
        this("");
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name ;
    }

    public String setName(String name) {
        String oldName = this.name ;
        this.name = name ;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange("name", oldName, name);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertySupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Then the following code:

```
Bean bean = new Bean();
StringProperty nameProperty() = new JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder()
        .bean(bean)
        .name("name")
        .build();
nameProperty().addListener((obs, oldName, newName) -> System.out.println("name changed from "+oldName+" to "+newName));
bean.setName("James");
System.out.println(nameProperty().get());
```

will produce the output:

```
name changed from to James 
James
```

If the JavaBean does not support `PropertyChangeListener`s, then changes to the bean via `bean.setName(...)` will not propagate to `ChangeListener`s or `InvalidationListener`s registered with the `JavaBeanStringProperty`.

So if the bean is simply

```
public class Bean {

    public Bean() {
        this("");
    }

    public Bean(String name) {
        this.name = name ;
    }

    private String name ;

    public String getName() {
        return name ;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name ;
    }
}
```

The JavaBeanStringProperty would have no way to observe the change, so the change listener would never be invoked by a call to `bean.setName()`. So the test code above would simply output

```
James
```

Comment: +1 good explanation. The JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder will add PropertyChangeListener support for the bean. From the answer it sounds to me like the user should add that support himself to the bean.

Comment: Not quite: the `JavaBeanStringProperty` does not add `PropertyChangeListener` support to the bean. Answer updated to clarify.

Comment: Would you mind if I ask you to also show a sample Java Bean with and without PropertyChangeListener support?

Comment: @James_D, thank you. Is there a similarly elegant solution for collection properties, like List<Client>?

Comment: Shame one has to depend on the java.desktop module (which includes Swing, AWT) just to use this

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587113/javabeanproperties-in-javafx-without-pulling-in-java-desktop-swing-awt