# Using POJOs as model layer in JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm creating simple JavaFX application. I want my model layer to be completely independent from JavaFX - no `StringProperty`, `IntegerProperty` and etc. as fields. I want it to be POJO. Main reason to do so is that I want it to be Serializable. 
I've created `DataRepository` - simple CRUD-like interface and some implementations of it, so I can at anytime change where I store my data - XML file, SQLite database or anything else. I also have to somehow connect my data storage with JavaFX (to display its content in TableView), so I decided to create my implementation of `ObservableList` which wraps my repository. My question is - is there any other way? `ObservableList` contains about 30 methods to implement and it looks like I'm doing something wrong.

My (simplified) model:

```
public class Movie implements Serializable {

    private String title;
    private String director;

    public Movie() {

    }

    public Movie(String title, String director) {
        this.title = title;
        this.director = director;
    }

    // Getters and setters, equals etc...
}
```

MovieRepository:

```
public interface MovieRepository {

    public void add(Movie movie);

    public void remove(String title);

    public void remove(int index);

    public Movie get(String title);

    public Movie get(int index);

    public List<Movie> getAll();
}
```

Controller for my main view:

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Movie> movieTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Movie, String> movieTitleColumn;
    @FXML
    private Label titleLabel;

    private MovieRepository movies = new DBMovieRepository(); //MovieRepository implementation which uses SQLite DB to store data
    private MainApp app;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        movieTable.setItems(new ObservableMovies(movies));
        // ObservableMovies is my implementation of ObservableList
        // It basically wraps methods from MovieRepository 
        // and notifies listeners
        showMovieDetails(null);

        movieTitleColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getTitle()));
        movieTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
        .addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> showMovieDetails(newValue));
    }

    private void showMovieDetails(Movie movie) {
        if(movie != null) {
            titleLabel.setText(movie.getTitle());
        } else {
            titleLabel.setText("");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleNew() {
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        app.showNewMovieDialog(movie);
        movieTable.getItems().add(movie);
    }

    public void setApp(MainApp app) {
        this.app = app;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't just mark your properties as `transient`? Then you just need to wrap them around you values and it will be both JavaFX compilant and `Serializable`. Also I didn't understand, why you would implement your own `ObversableList`. There are methods in `FXCollections` to create those from plain `java.util.Collections`. But if you really need to implement it, you can inherit from `ObservableListBase`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options here (maybe more), which are covered in other questions on this site. However, for convenience, I'll summarize them here too.

**1. Use JavaFX Properties and make the class Serializable**

You can do this with a custom serialized form. Make the JavaFX properties `transient` and implement `readObject` and `writeObject` to store the values they wrap:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Movie implements Serializable {

    private transient StringProperty title = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private transient StringProperty director = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Movie() {

    }

    public Movie(String title, String director) {
        setTitle(title);
        setDirector(director);
    }



    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getDirector(), getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;

        Movie other = (Movie) obj;
        return Objects.equals(getTitle(), other.getTitle()) 
                && Objects.equals(getDirector(), other.getDirector());

    }

    public final StringProperty titleProperty() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public final String getTitle() {
        return this.titleProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setTitle(final String title) {
        this.titleProperty().set(title);
    }

    public final StringProperty directorProperty() {
        return this.director;
    }

    public final String getDirector() {
        return this.directorProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setDirector(final String director) {
        this.directorProperty().set(director);
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream s) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        s.defaultReadObject();
        title = new SimpleStringProperty((String) s.readObject());
        director = new SimpleStringProperty((String) s.readObject());
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException {
        s.defaultWriteObject();
        s.writeObject(getTitle());
        s.writeObject(getDirector());
    }

}
```

**2. Use a POJO with "bound properties".**

See [JavaBean wrapping with JavaFX Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522130/javafx-properties-wrapping-bean) for details. In brief:

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

public class Movie {

    private String title ;
    private String director ;
    private final PropertyChangeSupport propertySupport ;

    public Movie(String title, String director) {
        this.title = title ;
        this.director = director ;
        this.propertySupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public Movie() {
        this("", "");
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title ;
    }

    public String setTitle(String title) {
        String oldTitle = this.title ;
        this.title = title ;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange("title", oldTitle, title);
    }

    // similarly for director...

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertySupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    // hashCode and equals...
}
```

For wanting to wrap your repository as an observable list, instead wrap it with a repository implementation that uses an observable list:

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;


public class ObservableMovieRepository implements MovieRepository {

    private final MovieRepository repository ;
    private final ObservableList<Movie> movieList;


    public ObservableMovieRepository(MovieRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository ;
        this.movieList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(repository.getAll());
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Movie movie) {
        repository.add(movie);
        movieList.add(movie);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(String title) {
        Movie movie = get(title);
        repository.remove(title);
        movieList.remove(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(int index) {
        repository.remove(index);
        movieList.remove(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Movie get(String title) {
        return repository.get(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Movie get(int index) {
        return movieList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Movie> getAll() {
        return movieList ;
    }

}
```

This uses the standard `ObservableList` implementation that copies an existing list on creation, and the implementation keeps that list in sync with the list in the wrapped repository. Now your UI code can do

```
ObservableMovieRepository movies = new ObservableMovieRepository(new DBMovieRepository());

// ...

movieTable.setItems(movies.getAll());
```

With the `Movie` class above, you would just do

```
movieTitleColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().titleProperty());
```

If you use the POJO version you can do

```
movieTitleColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
    try {
        return new JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder()
            .bean(cellData.getValue())
            .name("title")
            .build();
    } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
}
```

Comment: I wanted my `DataRepository` to be a 'black-box' - when asked, it just spits out the data needed for the application, but rest the application should not know how data is stored (as I said before, it could be read from XML or database or antyhing else). So I assumed that I have to have some layer which will connect my data source with gui/controller and `ObservableList` looked like good way to go.

Comment: You probably need to post some code to show what you mean. I still don't see why you wouldn't  just use the provided implementation.

Comment: Ok, I will try to come up with some minimal working example and I will post it in edit the question

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be multiple question in here, so I'm not really sure, if I understood you correctly, but I will try to split it up a bit.

> I want my model layer to be completely independent from JavaFX - no
>   StringProperty, IntegerProperty and etc. as fields. I want it to be
>   POJO.

You could mark your properties as `transient`. Then you just need to wrap them around your values and it will be both JavaFX compliant and `Serializable`. You just have to propagate changes back to your backing attributes.

> I also have to somehow connect my data storage with JavaFX (to display
>   its content in TableView), so I decided to create my implementation of
>   ObservableList which wraps my repository. My question is - is there
>   any other way?

Very limited information on this and I really don't know, why you would need to create your own implementation of `ObservableList`, but to keep it POJO, you could maintain plain `java.util.Collections` in your bean and provide transient `ObservableList`s, which you can create on creation by wrapping your `java.util.List`s in your POJO. You can find those methods in the `FXCollections` utility class.

> ObservableList contains about 30 methods to implement and it looks
>   like I'm doing something wrong.

If you *really* need to implement it, you can inherit from `ObservableListBase`.