# How to bind a JavaFX 8 object to a java variable?

Tags: java, variables, javafx, properties, bind

I'm trying to bind a TextField to a String (the attribute "nombre") in my program. I've seen that you can bind two JavaFX objects with the `bind()` method, but since java variables don't have properties, I am unable to use it in order to bind my TextField to a String. Here's the class where I'm trying to achieve this (without getters and setters):

```
public class NodoJugadores implements Serializable
{
private String nombre;
private int cedula;
private String sexo;
private int edad;
private String equipo;
private int categoria;
private int puntos;
private NodoJugadores proximo;
private NodoJugadores hijoIzquierdo;
private NodoJugadores hijoDerecho;

public NodoJugadores(String nombre, int cedula, String sexo, int edad, String equipo, int categoria, int puntos, NodoJugadores proximo)
{
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.cedula = cedula;
    this.sexo = sexo;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.equipo = equipo;
    this.categoria = categoria;
    this.puntos = puntos;
    this.proximo = proximo;
}

public NodoJugadores(String nombre, int cedula, String sexo, int edad, String equipo, int categoria, int puntos, NodoJugadores hijoIzquierdo, NodoJugadores hijoDerecho) 
{
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.cedula = cedula;
    this.sexo = sexo;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.equipo = equipo;
    this.categoria = categoria;
    this.puntos = puntos;
    this.hijoIzquierdo = hijoIzquierdo;
    this.hijoDerecho = hijoDerecho;
}

public void llenarGrid(GridPane grid)
{

    if(sexo.equalsIgnoreCase("m"))
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++)
        {
            TextField text = new TextField(nombre);

            grid.add(text, i, 0);
        }
    }
}

static final long serialVersionUID = 8925409;
}
```

Please, try to explain with an actual example of how this would work. I would greatly appreciate it. Also, it's worth mentioning that I can't convert my String to a StringProperty because I'm Serializing the class.

Comment: You can use a `StringProperty` and still make the class `Serializable`. You just have to define a custom serialized form.

Comment: @James_D I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with custom serializing, How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1: Use a `StringProperty`**

Use a `StringProperty` and a custom serialized form to make the class `Serializable`:

```
public class NodoJugadores implements Serializable {

    private final transient StringProperty nombre = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public StringProperty nombreProperty() {
        return nombre ;
    }

    public final String getNombre() {
        return nombreProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setNombre(String nombre) {
        nombreProperty().set(nombre);
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException {
        s.defaultWriteObject();
        s.writeObject(getNombre());
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream s) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        s.defaultReadObject();
        this.nombre = new SimpleStringProperty((String) s.readObject());
    }
}
```

**Solution 2: Use `PropertyChangeListener`s and a `JavaBeanPropertyAdapter`**

This is covered in [JavaBean wrapping with JavaFX Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522130/javafx-properties-wrapping-bean), but basically you would do

```
public class NodoJugadores implements Serializable {

    private String nombre ;

    private final PropertyChangeSupport pcs ;

    public NodoJugadores() {
        this.pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre ;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        String oldNombre = this.nombre ;
        this.nombre = nombre ;
        pcs.firePropertyChange("nombre", oldNombre, this.nombre);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

}
```

Then in your UI code you can do

```
Label nombreLabel = new Label();
NodoJugadores nj = new NodoJugadores();
nombreLabel.textProperty().bind(new JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder()
    .bean(nj)
    .name("nombre")
    .build());
```