# ComboBox does not observe changes made in SimpleObjectProperty

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Assume I have such simple domain POJO class:

```
package sample;

    public class Item {

        private String name;
        private String state;

        public Item() {}

        public Item(String name, String state) {
            this.name = name;
            this.state = state;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getState() {
            return state;
        }

        public void setState(String state) {
            this.state = state;
        }
  }
```

And assume that I have one restriction: I am not allowed to make any changes to this class. So I need to write a wrapper, right?

```
package sample;

    import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

    public class ItemWrapper {

        private ObjectProperty<Item> itemProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        private Item item;


        public ItemWrapper(Item item) {
            setItem(item);
        }

        public Item getItem() {
            return itemProperty.get();
        }

        public void setItem(Item item) {
            this.item = item;
            itemProperty.set(item);
        }

        public ObjectProperty<Item> itemProperty(){
            return itemProperty;
        }

    }
```

Then assume that I have a little JavaFX app which can show a list of items and has possibility to change item's state. Let's look at it.

*Main.java*

```
package sample;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Main extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
            primaryStage.setTitle("Item View");
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 100));
            primaryStage.show();
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

*Sample.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

  <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="108.0" prefWidth="225.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
     <children>
        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" text="show item" />
        <ComboBox fx:id="cbxItemsSelector" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="31.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
        <Button fx:id="btnChangeState" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="65.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#changeItemState" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="85.0" text="change state" />
     </children>
  </AnchorPane>
```

*Controller.java*

```
package sample;

    import javafx.beans.Observable;
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
    import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
    import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
    import javafx.util.Callback;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    public class Controller {

        @FXML
        private ComboBox<ItemWrapper> cbxItemsSelector;

        private ObservableList<ItemWrapper> items;

        public void initialize(){
            loadItems();
            customizeSelectorCellView();
        }

        private void loadItems() {
            List<Item> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
            itemsList.add(new Item("first item","initialized"));
            itemsList.add(new Item("second item","initialized"));

            List<ItemWrapper> itemWrappers = itemsList.stream().map(ItemWrapper::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
            items = FXCollections.observableList(itemWrappers,wrapper -> new Observable[]{wrapper.itemProperty()});

            cbxItemsSelector.setItems(items);
        }

        private void customizeSelectorCellView(){


            cbxItemsSelector.setButtonCell(new ListCell<ItemWrapper>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(ItemWrapper itemWrapper, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(itemWrapper, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setText("");
                    } else {
                        setText(itemWrapper.getItem().getName());
                    }
                }
            });
            cbxItemsSelector.setCellFactory(
                    new Callback<ListView<ItemWrapper>, ListCell<ItemWrapper>>() {
                        @Override
                        public ListCell<ItemWrapper> call(ListView<ItemWrapper> p) {
                            ListCell cell = new ListCell<ItemWrapper>() {
                                @Override
                                protected void updateItem(ItemWrapper itemWrapper, boolean empty) {
                                    //System.out.println("update item");
                                    super.updateItem(itemWrapper, empty);
                                    if (empty) {
                                        setText("");
                                    } else {
                                        Item item = itemWrapper.getItem();
                                        setText(String.format("name: %s\n state: %s\n",item.getName(),item.getState()));
                                    }
                                }
                            };return cell;
                        }
                    }
            );
        }

        @FXML
        public void changeItemState(){
            ItemWrapper selectedItemWrapper =  cbxItemsSelector.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if (selectedItemWrapper == null) return;

            Item item = selectedItemWrapper.getItem();
            item.setState("started");

        }
    }
```

The problem is that the comboBox does not see changes applied after some of item's state updated. The reason of the problem is that I only change object's (i.e Item) fields and I don't set new Item via `setItem` method.
So it seems that the fields changes are not observable.
I also know that IF I replace `SimpleObjectProperty` to two `StringProperty` (for name and state fields) in `ItemWrapper` class it will work. But I don't want to make field duplication. What If I would have 100 fields in `Item` class?

And I have two questions:
1) How can I make ComboBox see changes made by some other external side in any field in `Item` class without field duplication (without creating additional field properties) ? Maybe should I use some special binding?
2) Is there a way to get rid of Wrapper class while stay domain `Item` class unmodified?

Answer (score 0):

For what I know, `PropertyChangeListener` need to be created and registered. Take a loo at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day. :)

Comment: It's about Java Beans. I am using javaFX. Latter shloud do it more elegant via Observer pattern

Comment: I found a similar solution  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522130/javafx-properties-wrapping-bean/23524537#23524537 but it requires to modify domain class