# JavaBeanProperties in JavaFX without pulling in java.desktop (Swing, AWT)

Tags: java, swing, javafx, java-11, java-platform-module-system

I have some model classes that are instantiated many times and have *many* fields. While I could initialize all fields as `Simple*Property`s, this significantly slows performance due to the allocations (and lazy-creating the properties is not an option).

Thus, I would prefer to use `JavaBeanProperties` to create on-demand bindings where needed in the application like so (see this answer for a full example [JavaBean wrapping with JavaFX Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522130/javabean-wrapping-with-javafx-properties)):

```
Entity bean = ...
StringProperty nameProperty = JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder()
  .bean(bean)
  .name("name")
  .build();
```

However, I do not want to depend on `java.desktop` and related Swing components in my `module-info.java`

I could potentially re-write the desired functionality by setting a SimpleIntegerProperty that is incremented on each of the Entity's set* methods, and then add listeners in the GUI, but this is still less efficient (unnecessary updates) and expressive as using `JavaBean*Property`s

How may I use JavaBeanProperties (or similar on-demand binding functionality) without using java.desktop?

Comment: You've described a requirement or specification, but asked no question. What is your question?

Comment: How may I use JavaBeanProperties (or similar on-demand binding functionality) without using java.desktop?

Comment: The question should be included above. Please [edit] the post to add it.

Comment: Sure; I assumed the title made the question apparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a generic solution that doesn’t use Reflection at all:

```
public class DelegatingProperty<B,T> extends ObjectPropertyBase<T>
                                     implements JavaBeanProperty<T> {
    /**
     * Create a property without PropertyChangeEvent based notification.
     */
    public static <O, V> JavaBeanProperty<V> get(O bean, String name,
        Function<? super O, ? extends V> getter,
        BiConsumer<? super O, ? super V> setter) {
        return new DelegatingProperty<>(bean, name, getter, setter, null, null);
    }
    /**
     * Create a property with PropertyChangeEvent based notification.
     */
    public static <O, V> JavaBeanProperty<V> get(O bean, String name,
        Function<? super O, ? extends V> getter, BiConsumer<? super O, ? super V> setter,
        BiConsumer<? super O, ? super PropertyChangeListener> register,
        BiConsumer<? super O, ? super PropertyChangeListener> unregister) {
        return new DelegatingProperty<>(bean, name, getter, setter, register, unregister);
    }
    B bean;
    String name;
    Function<? super B, ? extends T> getter;
    BiConsumer<? super B, ? super T> setter;
    BiConsumer<? super B, ? super PropertyChangeListener> unregister;
    PropertyChangeListener listener;

    private DelegatingProperty(B bean, String name,
        Function<? super B, ? extends T> getter,
        BiConsumer<? super B, ? super T> setter,
        BiConsumer<? super B, ? super PropertyChangeListener> register,
        BiConsumer<? super B, ? super PropertyChangeListener> unregister) {
        this.bean = Objects.requireNonNull(bean);
        this.name = name;
        this.getter = Objects.requireNonNull(getter);
        this.setter = Objects.requireNonNull(setter);
        if(register != null || unregister != null) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(register);
            this.unregister = Objects.requireNonNull(unregister);
            register.accept(bean, listener = event -> fireValueChangedEvent());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getBean() {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public T get() {
        return getter.apply(bean);
    }

    @Override
    public void set(T value) {
        if(isBound()) throw new IllegalStateException("bound property");
        T old = getter.apply(bean);
        setter.accept(bean, value);
        T now = getter.apply(bean);
        if(!Objects.equals(old, now)) fireValueChangedEvent();
    }

    @Override
    protected void invalidated() {
        if(isBound()) {
            setter.accept(bean, super.get());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void fireValueChangedEvent() {
        super.fireValueChangedEvent();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        if(unregister != null && listener != null) {
            unregister.accept(bean, listener);
            listener = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, to stay at your example, you could get the `name` property of `Entity` as

```
JavaBeanProperty<String> prop = DelegatingProperty.get(bean, "name",
    Entity::getName, Entity::setName,
    Entity::addPropertyChangeListener, Entity::removePropertyChangeListener);
```

It’s more verbose, but on the other hand, provides more compile time safety, as the presence of all methods required for the property is checked at compile-time, and will likely have a higher runtime performance.

When you have a lot of properties in one bean class with event support, you may benefit from a dedicated factory method, e.g.

```
public static <V> JavaBeanProperty<V> property(Entity theBean, String name,
    Function<? super Entity, ? extends V> getter,
    BiConsumer<? super Entity, ? super V> setter) {
    return DelegatingProperty.get(theBean, name, getter, setter,
        Entity::addPropertyChangeListener, Entity::removePropertyChangeListener);
}
```

which you then can use as

```
JavaBeanProperty<String> nameProp
    = property(bean, "name", Entity::getName, Entity::setName);
JavaBeanProperty<String> otherProp
    = property(bean, "other", Entity::getOther, Entity::setOther);
```

Of course, it would also be possible to provide them via instance methods of the bean itself instead of a `static` factory method, too, perhaps with a lazily populated field holding the property, etc.

There are several roads you can go from this starting point.

Comment: This answer is awesome! I created classes JBObjectProperty<B, P> (https://gist.github.com/AugustNagro/d01a3a2c0d5cb64a938cb9c04fe11c47), JBStringProperty<P>, etc, and re-implemented a few other java.desktop.beans classes like java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport (https://gist.github.com/AugustNagro/789b1c5dd173497806108d74933f383b). Something along these lines would make a nice contribution to OpenJFX I think