# JavaBeanBooleanPropertyBuilder for "Beans" without setters

Tags: java, javafx, properties, binding, javafx-8

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522130/javabean-wrapping-with-javafx-properties) for connecting a Java Bean as property binding with an existing JavaFX property. The binding should target a boolean property:

```
class MyClass {

    private boolean loaded;

    public boolean isLoaded() {

        return loaded;
    }

    // Value changed internally
}
```

For real beans, meaning beans with setters the following works like a charm. But I've the problem that **there's no setter** for the loaded property, just because it's set internally and **shouldn't be modifyable** for external classes.

```
BooleanProperty loadedProeprty = new JavaBeanBooleanPropertyBuilder()
    .bean(bean)
    .name("loaded")
    .getter("isLoaded")
    .build();
```

Is there any way to create still a property for such "beans" **without** a setter? For now I just get a `NoSuchMethodException` for the expected setter `MyClass.setLoaded(boolean)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ReadOnlyJavaBeanBooleanPropertyBuilder` instead.

Normal properties in JavaFX are always read/write and thus require a setter.  The read only variant creates a read only property and thus does not require a setter.

Comment: Some explanation as to why this will solve the problem would make this a much better answer.