# hibernate 5 one-to-many with observablelist

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8

i got two classes which i "hibernated" already.
One of them (class Urlaub) holds an `ObservableList<Votes> vote` with corresponding getters/setter/property. Second class (class Votes) should be mapped within a one-2-many relation but i don´t know how.

My mapping for class Urlaub is:

```html
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="de.sul.urlaubsplaner.model.Urlaub" table="urlaub_data" catalog="urlaub">
        <id name="iddata" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id_data" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="iduser" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id_user" />
        </property>
        <property name="startDate" type="java.time.LocalDate">
            <column name="start_date" />
        </property>
        <property name="endDate" type="java.time.LocalDate">
            <column name="end_date" />
        </property>
        <property name="days" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="days" />
        </property>
        <property name="daysSum" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="daysSum" />
        </property>
        <property name="status" type="string">
            <column name="status" length="255" />
        </property>
        <property name="created" type="java.time.LocalDateTime">
            <column name="created"/>
        </property>
        <property name="lastChange" type="java.time.LocalDateTime">
            <column name="last_change"/>
        </property>
        <set name="voteUp" cascade="all">
            <key column="id_data"/>
            <one-to-many class="de.sul.urlaubsplaner.model.UserVote"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

for votes

```html
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="de.sul.urlaubsplaner.model.UserVote" table="urlaub_vote" catalog="urlaub">
        <id name="id_vote" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id_vote" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="id_data" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id_data"/>
        </property>
        <property name="id_user" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id_user"/>
        </property>
        <property name="status" type="string">
            <column name="status" />
        </property>
        <property name="created" type="java.time.LocalDateTime">
            <column name="created"/>
        </property>
        <property name="lastChange" type="java.time.LocalDateTime">
            <column name="last_change"/>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Both id_data belong together...
What i like to do is call

```
List<Urlaub> urlaub = (List<Urlaub>) session.createCriteria(Urlaub.class).list();
```

which has also all UserVotes which i then could cast to ObservableList.
Any idea? Thx
Btw sry for to knowing how to insert xml data correctly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of trail and error just found the solution.
First of all as a hibernate beginner it is a pain to use the netbeans hibernate wizard as it uses old xml hibernate config syntax whereas hibernate as i use it can be used with newer class syntax. So changing the following lines at first helped to change the error messages which then led to the solution
from:

```
<mapping resource="de/superinge/urlaubsplaner/model/Urlaub.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="de/superinge/urlaubsplaner/model/UserVote.hbm.xml"/>
```

to:

```
<mapping class="de.superinge.urlaubsplaner.model.Urlaub"/>
<mapping class="de.superinge.urlaubsplaner.model.UserVote"/>
```

Then in the my Urlaub.class where i "link" the UserVote i had to add a OneToMany relationship with the column name that is mapped in UserVote in this case iddata...

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "iddata")
public List<UserVote> getVoteUp(){
    return voteUp;
}
```

Then all worked like charm..hope this helps somebody